# I am getting fine results in ideone but SPOJ is not accepting my solution. The link is given below

Tags: java, performance

http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL2/

It works fine when I tested with some of the test cases. But SPOJ says wrong answer. What can I do so that they accept the code?

```
import java.util.*;

class testw
{   
public static void main(String args[])
{
       Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
       int t=obj.nextInt();
       int count = t;
       int arr[]= new int[t];
       int res[] =new int[t];
       int i=0;
       while(t>0)
       {
           arr[i]=obj.nextInt();
           res[i]=func(arr[i]);
           i++;
           t--;
       }

       for(int j=0; j<count; j++) 
       {
           System.out.println(res[j]);
        }
    }

    public static int func(int a)
    {
        int f=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
        {
            f= f*i;
        }
        return f;
    }}
```

Comment: Is SPOJ the one that requires the class to be named 'Main'?

Comment: I tried after renaming the class "Main"...but still the same result

Comment: Hint: the assignment is tagged with #big-numbers. n can be up to 100. And 100! is a very, very large numbers. int has only 32 bits.

Comment: Since you're using java, use BigInteger since 100! will be too big to fit in an int or even a long. Since the problem statement specifies that n will 100 at most, you can just create an array of BigIntegers of size 100 and precompute the factorials there. To get n!, simply look it up in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unable to handle really big numbers. You can see that problem description constraints state that `1 ≤ n ≤ 100`. You should be aware that `100!` has 159 digits while `int` type that you have used is bound by a couple of billions (i.e. about 10 digits).

Your code works fine on [Ideone](http://ideone.com) because you try it with small numbers. You should expect that during correctness verification [Spoj](http://spoj.com) use more advanced test cases (including bigger numbers).